# Must a converging sequence converge to a fixed point?

Tags: sequences-and-series, fixed-point-theorems

I am trying to show that the infinite tetration
$\lim_{n \to \infty}$$^{n}x$ converges for real values of $x$ within $[e^{-e},e^{\frac{1}{e}}]$. To do so, I examined the fixed points of the following recursive function.
$$^{n+1}x=x^{^{n}x}$$
Then, the desired result is obtained by examining the value of the iteration function's derivatives. However, I wonder if the following proposition is true: if a sequence $f$ converges, then it must converge to a fixed point. If it is true, how shall I prove it? Thank you!

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, if you are given an infinite sequence of real numbers $~\langle a_n\rangle,~$ then this sequence converges if and only if there exists a fixed (finite) real number $~L,~$ such that for any $~\epsilon > 0,~$ there exists an $~N \in \Bbb{Z^+},~$ such that for all positive integers $~n \geq N,~ |a_n - L| < \epsilon.~$  In effect this means that the sequence is convergent if and only if there exists an $~L,~$ such that the sequence converges to $~L.$  Easy to show that for a given sequence, if the value $~L~$ exists, it must be unique.

Answer (score 0):

If the requirements of the Banach fixed-point theorem are fulfilled this is true.
If you have a sequence of a function being iterated and the function is constricting and invariant then the limit of the sequence will be that function’s fixed point.

Comment: Being contractive is not enough; it must also be invariant.

Answer (score 0):

If the function is continuous, what you claim is true. You can simply observe that if $x_n \to L$, then, taking limits on $x_{n+1} = g(x_n)$, leads to $L = g(L)$.